# What can I do with Rotten Flesh?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have about 10 double chests of rotten flesh (my zombie pigman farm is working nicely thank you very much).

While rotten flesh is great for dogs, I just can't imagine using any more than a hand full of stacks for them.

I have also been using it for some decay timers.  But that uses 1 every 5 minutes.  So, in about a third of a year I'll have used it up....

Does Rotten Flesh have any other uses?

Comment: I voted to close this not because the question is bad, but because the wording really lends itself to inviting discussion. A question that just asked "what can I do with Rotten Flesh?" would be better than one asking if there's "anything creative you can think of to do with the rest."

Comment: I have reworded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rotten flesh is quite useless but it can be used as a good source of food. Despite having a 80% chance to drain your hunger, it heals 20% of your hunger. You can cure the hunger by drinking a bucket of milk, which may seem like inventory space waste, but still...

It does heal wolfs however without hungering them.

I honestly don't know what else you can do with it :/

As for the spider eyes and glass bottles, I recommend you start your own brewery (not beer, just potions). With the spider eyes, you can create a mundane potion or a potion of poison, or you could ferment the spiders eyes using mushrooms and sugar and create potion of invisibility, potion of weakness, potion of slowness or potion of harming.

For more information, I recommend looking at the relevant wikis:

- [Fermented Spider Eyes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fermented_Spider_Eye)
- [Spider Eyes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spider_Eye)
- [Zombie Flesh](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rotten_Flesh)

Comment: zombie flesh doesn't cause Poison but Hunger (and the effect is called that in-game)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I will edit it now

Answer (score 11):

Sell Rotten Flesh to a villager cleric. Then you can fill up the chests with emeralds,use them in trades or pack them into blocks to build with them or by putting them into blocks to occupy less space in the chests. Also,you can feed wolves with it. If you give rotten flesh to wolves when they have full health,they will enter love mode and breed. Giving (almost) ALL of the rotten flesh to the wolves will allow an army of 1000+ wolves in time! If you really don't want it anymore,you can throw it in lava or fire,but this is not the best solution.

Comment: At least according to the minecraft Wiki, Priests do not purchase rotten flesh.  Since when do priests offer up rotten flesh as a trade?

Comment: Since 1.8. @John

Comment: See this [link](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Trading) to see villager's trades. @John

Comment: This conversation looks very solipsistic at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @ReallyGoodPie, you can use rotten flesh as a source pf food, but you could also use it too breed wolves

Answer (score -5):

Rotten flesh can be used for dog food or TNT because you can put rotten flesh in a chest, put a lever next to the chest, flick the switch and ... BOOOOOM!!!!!! an explosion.

Answer (score -7):

You could lag people out if it is a multiplayer server.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Your answer is definitely correct, I've seen that work before, but I think you're getting downvoted because that's not a very nice thing to do. You might have more luck answering another Minecraft question that's less of a discussion.

Comment: Why to do this? The question was about of what to do with rotten flesh,and you answered something completly something off the question's topic. More than that,lagging people out of a server can be easily a lowly-man humour.