# How do I restore my wolf's health in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a few pet wolves' in creative mode on minecraft (Pc) and one of them is on very low health (Its tail is sagging). Is there any way I can heal him?

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 options. They are:

- Feed it some food. (Must be meat. Fish and plants will not work. Rotting flesh works.)
- Throw a splash potion of healing.

Usually people go for number 1 because they have excess rotting flesh, which the wolf eats. Whether the food is raw or cooked does not matter. The wolf will not get hunger or poisoning no matter what.

Comment: Agreed, rotten flesh is the most effective thing to use, as it's not particularly useful for anything else.

Comment: @shanodin There is a use for it [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165595/108497).

Answer (score 5):

You could always throw a Splash Potion of Healing at it.

Comment: But food is cheaper. It does not need you to go to the nether

Comment: @TheCodingMonster well, he is in creative mode on his world.

Comment: Oh didn't see that I was thinking about survival mode